# Set checkboxes with specified name and value

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the jquery DataTables plugin and I have added a checkbox to the table for selecting rows. I am using the FixedColumns extension which causes DataTables to create duplicate copies of the part of the table that does not scroll. Therefore, my page actually has two row select boxes - one visible and one hidden. My idea is when the visible one is clicked, to set the hidden one to the same checked state. I need something like this, but I'm not sure how to find the other checkbox by value. Maybe use a filter? Thanks.

```
// a row select checkbox changed. Set its hidden version created by datatables
function OnRowSelectCheckBoxClicked(cb) {
        var isChecked = cb.checked;
        var val = cb.value;
        // set any duplicate checkboxes with same value to same checked state.
        $('input[type=checkbox][name^="selectlesson"][value = "val"').not(cb).prop('checked', ischecked);
}
```

This seems to work:

```
        function OnRowSelectCheckBoxClicked(cb) {
        var isChecked = cb.checked;
        var val = cb.value;
        // set all duplicate checkboxes to same value.
        var s = 'input[type=checkbox][name^="selectlesson"][value="' + val +'"]';
        $(s).not(cb).prop('checked', isChecked);
    }
```

Comment: The argument to `.not()` is supposed to be a selector. What is in `cb.value`?

Comment: How are the two checkboxes arranged in the HTML? You can probably use DOM traversal functions to go from the visible one to the adjacent hidden one.

Comment: I thought not meant to not find the specified element.  I want to find its twin.  cb.value is the value= attribute of the checkbox that was clicked.  I'm not sure I want to depend on the DOM layout to find the other. Its a ways away I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't expand variables inside strings, you have to use explicit concatenation.

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name^=selectlesson][value="' + val + '"]').not(cb).prop('checked', ischecked);
```